# How Can Static Variables Within a Python Class Be Used in an Instance of the Class

Tags: python, django

In other languages, static variable are only accessible through the class name, and do not relate at all to an instance of that class.

I've been following the Django [Polls App Tutorial](http://polls.apps.PollsConfig).  It seems that when a model is declared, the fields of that model are static variables:

```py
class Question(models.Model):
    question_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField('date published')
```

However, the tutorial then demonstrates how the Django shell can be used:

```sh
>>> from polls.models import Question
>>> q = Question(question_text="What's new?", pub_date=timezone.now())
```

This is really confusing to me, as it seems that we are constructing, `q`, an object that is of type `Question`, but that somehow is capable of holding information (`question_test` and `pub_date`) that I thought was only related to the class, not the instance (static variables).

Can someone explain to me what is going on?

How is it possible that these bits of data are able to be assigned to an instance of the class?  Is this a Python or Django related thing?  If so, what does `q` even represent?  Does it represent just a row in the table?

This is pretty bizarre come from C++ where a static variable can't ever be related to an object of the class.

Comment: That's Django ORM. Read more here https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/models/.

Comment: This if a common misunderstanding. The fields are *not* accessible through the instance. They are used to *populate* the instance at creation; note that you get strings and dates as instance variables, not instances of the field classes.

Comment: @DanielRoseman, so just to be clear, the static variables, `question_text` and `pub_date` are only used to initialize some internal data inside of the object `q`?  How exactly does that work?  Do they just dynamically create instance data members within the object `q`?  It seems a bit odd because I would assume the class would just have a normal `__init__(self)` function, which would declare any internal data members it would need and then the instances would get their own copies of it.  It seems a bit odd that the static variables of the class are turned into instance variables upon creation.

Comment: @DanielRoseman, also, your comment is the closest thing answering my question so far, if you were to create an answer to my question, I would likely accept it.

Answer (score 2):

From what I know, `models.Model` has a meta class called `ModelBase`. So before a `Question` class create, the meta class will be triggered and attach attributes to a class. So when the class `Question` is created, it's already have that attribute and value. `Question` represent a table Question in your database

- `q = Question(question_text='foo', pub_date='2019-12-12')`
  This creaate an instance of `Question`.
- `q.save()` to perform an insert SQL to database
- Meta programming: https://stackabuse.com/python-metaclasses-and-metaprogramming/
- Django source code: https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/db/models/base.py

Answer (score 1):

The `Question` class represents an *entire* database table, and each attribute (model field) of the Question class represents a single column in that table.

When you initialize a model, for example:

```
question1 = Question(question_text='foo', pub_date='2019-12-12')
```

You create an *instance* of that model, which represents a single row in your Question table, however  `question1` won't hit the database until you call it's `save()` method:

```
question1.save()
```